# Custom UITableViewCell reloads row improperly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm having an issue which doesn't seem to have been asked on SO, or at least I can't think of the proper search terms to define my issue. Long story short, I have a UITableViewController that uses three different custom prototype cells. The cells each have a unique reuse identifier specified in the storyboard. In the table multiple instances of a given custom cell exist. Each prototype cell contains a UILabel (left-aligned) and a UIView control (button, switch, etc - right-aligned).

I've managed to get the layout of the cells and functionality in place. The issue I'm having is when the user scrolls the tableView. When a cell goes off of screen then returns, it is rendered improperly. Or at least it is drawn properly for a split second, and then the UILabel's position gets moved up and the UIView control is nowhere to be seen in the cell. The same thing happens when I use the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;` method to hide/show a cell dynamically, along with the `heightForRowAtIndexpath` method. As you can see in [the attached video](https://vid.me/YyYT), the cell does reload but the alignment of its contents isn't right (sorry for the watermark in the video).

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: How are you dequeuing the cell? `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath?`

Comment: Please your code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath `

Comment: I'm just using `dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier` since I could determine what the difference between this and the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The cell's constraints were being removed every time a cell was created. Guessing this caused some conflict with the reuse of cells. Once I removed the line `[self removeConstrains:self.constraints]` I was able to get the desired performance without the cells getting "stuck".

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting your cell outlets to their respective 'clean' states using [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)